# How to work with current working copy when moving to old branch in GIT?

Tags: git

I have a question concerning best practice in GIT. Imagine I create a branch called `hotfixes` and I add some fixes to it and then merge the branch with the master. Then I create a few other branches and merge them with the master.

After a few weeks I realize I need to add some more hot fixes so I locally move into the `hotfixes` branch. However since the master branch has proceeded in the past weeks and I switched to an older branch I now end up having a much older local working copy.

How can I make sure to be able to work in a branch I have created weeks ago and still have the current working directory as it is in the master? Is this done using the `rebase` command or would I have to delete the old branch and re-create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is I would like to always use the same branch or at least
>   the same name "hotfixes"

But why? I would recommend to create a branch that is directly related to the fix, i.e. `hotfix/missing_dll`, branch it off the current working branch (`master`, for example), and delete it after the merge. This ensures you are always up to date of your current work.

If you really *have* to use one branch continuously, you can just merge your current `master` to `hotfixes` every time you start working on it again. This will, however, create ugly merge commits that will eventually end up in your `master` branch.

The first apporach is much cleaner and less error-prone. If you have good reasons to continuously use a single `hotfixes` branch, please elaborate.

Edit: Aside other workflows, this is what is done in [this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) branching model.

Comment: Great, thank you for the explanation and the link! Just for my understanding is there a reason for the slash in `hotfix/missing_dll` or is it just the name of the branch?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason. Git stores your local branches in the `.git/refs/heads` folder. If you name your branch without slashes, e.g. `mybranch`, a file called `mybranch` is created in that folder, containing the SHA id of the commit your branch currently points to. If you crate a branch called `hotfix/myFix`, a *folder* is created in `.git/refs/heads` and a file named `myFix` is created in that folder: `.git/refs/heads/hotfix/myFix`. This can make branch managing easier if you have many branches. Some git GUIs also use this to improve handling of many branches, e.g. GitKraken.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, re-using that old hotfix branch (by merging or rebasing) is fundamentally wrong in any reasonable workflow. A hotfix branch is like a feature branch - you would not re-use those, either.

After you are done with your hotfix and it is merged back into your main branch, you can simply delete the hotfix branch. When you create it new (from `master`), later, all will be fine.

Deleting a merged branch in git does not change history at all, by the way. Branches in git are simply "sticky notes" pointing to a commit.  For example, `gitk` or `git log --graph --decorate master` will still show the actual branching commits indefinitely. It is actually completely impossible to delete the *commits* that were made between the `git checkout -b` and the `git merge`.

The manual covers this in detail:  https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell

Comment: Thank you! However when I simply delete it I would also loose all the history of that branch and couldn't see what I had done a few weeks ago in that branch, wouldn't I?

Comment: I suggest to read [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell), or even the whole chapter about branching, to understand how branches work in git.

Comment: Absolutely, @kowsky, thanks for bringing up the RTFM. 

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the particular convention is, but I tend to merge and branch again if there are major changes in the main version. This basically allows me to update the branched version. I tend to do this because if there are updates being accepted by the main version, that usually means they are working updates. 
Another thing that is possible is to make a copy of what you have changed, and alter those files when you make a branch from the updated main version.

Hope this helps, also curious to see what other people suggest.
Have a good day!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem is I would like to always use the same branch or at least the same name "hotfixes" (which wouldn't be possible when creating a new branch).

Comment: Yeah I see your dilemma, it is a good question I don't know if it is possible. Because when you branch the idea is that it doesn't get affected by changes to other branches/versions. So you can keep on editing your old branch, but if the changes to the main version are too many (in the wrong place) then you might not be able to merge them back without some complicated version control issues.